# Cannot start process from different directory

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a program in C++ that launches an executable. When I try to run the program, nothing happens. But when I try to run the program on the same directory and drive the exe is in, it does work.

Here's the code:

```
else if (result1 == 0) {
        int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow);
        {
            STARTUPINFO si = { 0 };
            PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = { 0 };
            si.cb = sizeof(si);
            CreateProcess(L"D:\\Games\\Origin Games\\Command and Conquer Red Alert\\RA95Launcher.exe", NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE, NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
```

When I do it like this:

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow);
        {
            STARTUPINFO si = { 0 };
            PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = { 0 };
            si.cb = sizeof(si);
            CreateProcess(L"D:\\Games\\Origin Games\\Command and Conquer Red Alert\\RA95Launcher.exe", NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE, NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, NULL, "D:\\Games\\Origin Games\\Command and Conquer Red Alert\\", &si, &pi);
```

I get the error:

> argument of type "const char *" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPCWSTR"

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check the return value of `CreateProcess`, and if the function fails call `GetLastError`.

Comment: What is the purpose of declaring the existence of `WinMain` there? (This makes it look like you've missed something fundamental. Please post a [mcve].)

Comment: @molbdnilo how do i do that?

Comment: yeah i just copied it because i didnt know how to do it

Comment: First of all, read [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessa).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you should set the `lpCurrentDirectory` parameter to the directory the exe is in.

See: [CreateProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw)

---

It's often that executables like `RA95Launcher.exe` are depending on other files. Usually these are reffered to by a `relative path` from perspective of the `Current Working Directory`.

If you launch the process from within the directory the exe is in, your automatically in the correct `Current Working Directory`. If you have the launcher running at a different location, you'll need to specify it.

Comment: When i change it i get this error: argument of type "const char *" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPCWSTR"   how do i fix this?

Comment: If you update your question with this adjustment we can see what actually goes wrong

Comment: You need to put the `L` operator in front of it, just as for the other string

Comment: I addded some additional explanation.

Answer (score 0):

> I get the error: argument of type "const char *" is incompatible with
> parameter of type "LPCWSTR"

This means that you're trying to pass incompatible type to function. `LPCWSTR` is `Windows.h` typedef for `const wchar_t*`(a UTF-16 string), but `CreateProcess` requires ANSI string(`LPCSTR`). You can either call the appropriate function, in this case - `CreateProcessW`(W at the end of the function name means it takes UTF-16 strings as parameters) or make your string ANSI by removing `L` before it.